# Override Zurb Foundation css in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I can't override the class "**.fixed**" in `foundation_and_overrides.scss` because the class "fixed" doesn't exist on that file, I searched it everywhere (ctrl + f on "**fixed**")

Or, I need to set its value "left" to none instead of "0". I don't know how to do it, I've already tried to override the css class directly on my header, or in application.css, but it doesn't work, I suspect the compiled foundation_and_overrides.css to takes the priority.

Also, I cannot change its value directly on the html element, because the javascript associated when scrolling destroy its css data.
[image: magellan-cannot-override]
my html:

```
<div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
  <dl class="sub-nav">
    <dd>
      <a href="/en/login">
        Log in
      </a>
    </dd>
    <dd class="active">
      <a href="/en/signin">
        Sign up
      </a>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

What the inspect element of chrome tells me:

```
enmedia="screen"  http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/foundation_and_overrides.css?body=1:4367
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

I cannot create a new class, and copy the "fixed" attribrutes there, I already tried it, on such case I also need to copy x classes because the fixed attributes are parents of others attributes.

Comment: try override with !important

Comment: thx, It works, but that's quite ugly, I'd prefer to set it on foundation_and_overrides, how can I do?

Comment: in that case you will have to define that class in your above mentioned external css file and make sure it was the last to be imported in your header so that it will prevail over others

Answer (score 1):

Class .fixed from top-bar components:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_top-bar.scss

there are two ways:
1. Set variables $include-html-top-bar-classes: false if you don't need the top-bar component 
2. Add some class with styles .your-class{left: none;} at the end of your styles and overwrite default .fixed